# fgetcsv reading only first line and breaking while loop

Tags: php

So, It is very odd that with certain files this program just breaks. I have input files with 500 rows on it, and it works just fine, but if I try to input 1000 lines or more, the program only gets the first row of the csv file (where the titles are) and breaks the whole while loop.

I noticed there were another questions that looked similar; however, when I read through it I realized they weren't calling fgetcsv() into a loop. In contrast, I am calling the function in a while loop.

My code looks like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
    $goe = fopen($target_file, "r");
    while($data = fgetcsv($goe, filesize($target_file))){
        if(!empty($data[0]) && !empty($data[2])){
            if($data[0] !='brand' && $data[2] !='MPN'){
                $string = $data[0] .' '. $data[2];
                $arrayOfSearches[$data[1]] = $string;    
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($target_file);
}
```

After debugging I realized it enter once in the while loop, it enters into the first if condition, but when it gets to the second one it never enters (makes sense since the first row are the titles which I don't want).

Any ideas?

Comment: `Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.` perhaps..... it's always worth reading the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: Perhaps, but I tried this too, and it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem, when reading a cvs file, the process was returning all rows in one line, but luckily I found the solution, just add this line to your PHP file:

`ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);`

Hope works for you.